# How to resize winform to top and not bottom c#

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

When i'm re sizing a winform it expands to the bottom and not to top.
How do I resize a form to the top instead bottom?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean resizing by code? Because when using mouse, it's a strange behavior when user intends to expand the bottom edge but it's extended on the top edge.

Comment: I think Niv means that if he changes the size programmatically it will grow to the bottom. ASFAIK that only works by simultaneously moving the window up.

Comment: It is simply because you are changing the Size, not the Location.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about changing the size of the form at run-time so it expands upwards, then you have to change the Location() property to move it up, as well as change the Height:

```
        int ExpandUpwardsInPixels = 50;
        this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y - ExpandUpwardsInPixels); // move it up 
        this.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height + ExpandUpwardsInPixels); // increase the height
```

An alternative approach would be to modify the Bounds() property:

```
        int ExpandUpwardsInPixels = 50;
        Rectangle bnds = this.Bounds;
        bnds.Offset(0, -ExpandUpwardsInPixels);
        bnds.Height = bnds.Height + ExpandUpwardsInPixels;
        this.Bounds = bnds;
```