# C# Label, grow height to top when resized in code

Tags: c#, winforms, label

CODE:

```
label1.height = current_height + 100;
```

This code will successfully resize the label but it is resizing downwards. I want it to be resized upward. I've read some threads that you need to set the anchor properties but those methods don't work for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Winforms or WPF?

Comment: *"you need to set the anchor properties but those methods don't work for me"* - what exactly have you tried and how don't work looks like?

Comment: set anchor properties to "TOP" then text alignment properties to TopCenter.

Comment: I have used winforms

Comment: *"Resizing upwards"* - is achieved by changing both: `Location` and `Size`. I'd say anchor "Bottom", but is it possible to see layout and screenshot first?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZnZZ1

here is it.

Comment: Single label, so you have to simply change location. Look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107189/1997232).

Comment: thank you. Why I couldn't find this question earlier

Answer (score 0):

You need to change top position:

```
int height = current_height + 100;
label1.Top -= height;
label1.Height += height;
```

[image]

and if you need to align text to the bottom, you just set TextAlign property to:

```
 label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
```

[image]